# Tidal Warrior and Islandwalk

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Tidal Warrior](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTidal%20Warrior%5d) has an ability which says:

> {T}: Target land becomes an Island until end of turn.

If I use this ability to change an opponent's land to an Island, then attack with a creature that has Islandwalk, would this mean that creature can't be blocked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Islandwalk prevents a creature from being blocked as long as the defending player controls an Island<sup>1</sup>.  It doesn't matter whether that Island used to be a different kind of land - after using Tidal Warrior's ability, your opponent controls an Island<sup>1</sup>, and creatures with Islandwalk cannot be blocked.

---

<sup>1. Note that "controls an Island" means "controls a permanent that has the subtype 'Island.'"  The name of the card is irrelevant.</sup>

Comment: Not quite, it doesn't care about the land being an island, it cares about the land having the subtype island, there are 5 cycles of lands that are non basic but have subtypes, in addition to the two cycles of basic lands and type changing or replacing effects.

Comment: You are correct, but what I said is not incorrect.  A land with the subtype "Island" *is* an Island, just as a creature with the subtype "Goblin" is a Goblin.  However, I agree that it is worth clarifying the difference between the subtype and the name of the card.

Comment: Yes that is true, and all lands named island will have the subtype island, but for the sake of those coming to ask questions here, or find answers to questions that were already asked, it's worth being clear.

Comment: If my opponent controls an Island enchanted with [Contaminated Ground](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193608), then according to the second sentence of this answer, my [Merrow Harbinger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=merrow+harbinger) will be unblockable because the card's name is still Island. That's incorrect though, for reasons others have already tried to point out.

Comment: @Rainbolt is right the answer still has some clarity issues, specify that being named island does not matter.

Comment: @Rainbolt No, that is not implied by the second sentence.  After playing Contaminated Ground, your land is no longer an Island.  It may be named Island, but it is not an Island.  Yes, that's confusing.  But I think that you're being more pedantic than is necessary to answer the question.

Comment: @Andrew I've already addressed that.

Comment: Not quite, you say that being typed an island matters but not that being named island doesn't. An island typed swamp like rainbolt suggests would not trigger islandwalk.

Comment: @BJMyers Don't focus on the exact question asked so much that you confuse people reading your answer. The goal is to allow not only the person asking the question to understand, but future readers, That's why my explanation goes on to give examples and an explanation of landwalk. If all we wanted to do was answer the question we only need one word, yes or no.

Comment: @Andrew In my opinion, you guys are making the answer way more confusing than it has to be by pulling in corner cases about dual lands, etc.  Nevertheless, I've edited my footnote to be as clear as possible while still scoping the answer to the question asked.

Comment: @BJMyers I withdraw my previous comment (but I won't delete it yet, so others can see the mistake I made). I wasn't trying to be pedantic about your choice of English words - I truly thought that the answer was using incorrect game terminology. I realized I was wrong when I found this rule that totally supports your answer: `109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.`

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The land was granted the Island type, and Islandwalk checks the type of the card (not its name).

> 702.14c A creature with landwalk can’t be blocked as long as the defending player controls at least one land with the specified subtype (as in “islandwalk”), with the specified supertype (as in “legendary landwalk”), without the specified supertype (as in “nonbasic landwalk”), or with both the specified supertype and the specified subtype (as in “snow swampwalk”). (See rule 509, “Declare Blockers Step.”)

Incidentally, that also means you can tap it for blue mana.

> 305.6. The basic land types are Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and Forest. If an object uses the words “basic land type,” it’s referring to one of these subtypes. A land with a basic land type has the intrinsic ability “{T}: Add [mana symbol] to your mana pool,” even if the text box doesn’t actually contain that text or the object has no text box. For Plains, [mana symbol] is {W}; for Islands, {U}; for Swamps, {B}; for Mountains, {R}; and for Forests, {G}. See rule 107.4a. See also rule 605, “Mana Abilities.”

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Islandwalk, and any other landwalk ability doesn't care why the land meets the condition, only that it does, this means Islandwalk works on any land subtyped island including:

- Original dual lands like [Volcanic Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVolcanic%20Island%5d)
- Shock Lands like [Breeding Pool](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBreeding%20Pool%5d)
- Battle Lands like [Sunken Hollow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSunken%20Hollow%5d)
- Cycling Dual Lands like [Irrigated Farmland](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIrrigated%20Farmland%5d)
- [Moonring Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoonring%20Island%5d)
- [Snow-Covered Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnow-Covered%20Island%5d)
- normal basic Islands
- Lands under the effect of a type changing (replacement) effect (like [Tidal Warrior](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTidal%20Warrior%5d))
- Lands under the effect of a type changing (addition) effect (like [Aquitect's Will](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAquitect%27s%5d%2b%5bWill%5d))

Type changing of lands into islands was used heavily when [Stormtide Leviathan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStormtide%20Leviathan%5d) was played, since the leviathan did the type changing, became unblockable, and prevented most other creatures from attacking.

Other types of landwalk exist, other than the walks for the basic land types like:

- Legendary Landwalk (as seen on [Ayumi, the Last Visitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAyumi%2c%20the%20Last%20Visitor%5d))
- Desertwalk (as seen on [Desert Nomads](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesert%20Nomads%5d))
- Nonbasic Landwalk (as seen on [Dryad Sophisticate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDryad%20Sophisticate%5d))
- Snow (basic)walk (as seen on [Rime Dryad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRime%20Dryad%5d))
- Snow Landwalk (as seen on [Zombie Musher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZombie%20Musher%5d))
- Denimwalk (only seen on [Hurloon Wrangler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHurloon%20Wrangler%5d) and in the legends of Magic: the Gathering play, caused someone to respond to combat by taking off their pants. Also technically not a 'land'walk)

Comment: This is a very detailed explanation of Landwalk, but only the first 19 words address the question.